# Swift how to turn on the flash mode for custom camera

Tags: ios, swift

When I build the custom camera, I set the flash mode of the current device by the following code:

```
            try currentDevice.lockForConfiguration()
            currentDevice.flashMode = .on
            currentDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
```

My capture picture function is the default `captureOutput` function (override by `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`) with works well but only the flash mode didn't work.

```
    func captureOutput(
        _ output: AVCaptureOutput,
        didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
        from connection: AVCaptureConnection
    ) {
        if !takePicture {
            return
        }

        takePicture = false
        
        guard let cvBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: cvBuffer)
        let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
        savePicture(image: uiImage)
    }
```

Comment: "When I build the custom camera"  What does building a custom camera mean?

Comment: Please, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286041/swift-3-how-do-i-enable-flash-on-custom-avfoundation-camera). It may help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `var flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode { get set }` is deprecated ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388116-flashmode))

Maybe you mean [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1648760-flashmode) `flashMode` which is set on `AVCapturePhotoSettings` and supersedes the deprecated one.

But if you need LED back light on you should use `.torchMode` on the `AVCaptureDevice` object.

In order to do that you need to make sure that the `currentDevice` has torch available.

```
guard currentDevice.isTorchAvailable else { ...fallbac... }
```

Then you need to lock the device for configuration.

```
try currentDevice.lockForConfiguration()
```

And set the desired torch mode.

```
currentDevice.torchMode = .on // or .off
```

Remember to unlock the device after you are done with configuration

```
currentDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
```

If you want to set the torch mode on with some level of intensity you could turn it on using this method (instead of `currentDevice.torchMode = .on`)

```
try currentDevice.setTorchModeOn(level: 0.3)
```